# How to compare two list to get matching elements and non matching elements

Tags: java, arraylist

Below point 1 and point 2 are my input, in below code i'm trying to compare both the Arraylist to get matching and nonmatching elements, But i'm geting only non matching records.

1. arraylist1 = [Check Document  Equals , Document Date Like Equals Between, Fund Number Like Equals , Account Number Like Equals In, Tin Like Equals , Company Number Like Equals , Dealer Number Like Equals In, Member Id Like Equals In, Group Id Like Equals In, Account Type Like Equals In, Document Type Code Like Equals In, Print  Equals , Test  two ]
2. arraylist2 = [Document Date Like
   Equals
   Between, Fund Number Equals
   Like, Account Number Like
   Equals
   In, Tin Equals
   Like, Company Number Equals
   Like, Dealer Number Like
   Equals]

3.when i'm trying to remove extra from  space "arrayList2" i'm getting below
[Document Date LikeEqualsBetween, Fund Number EqualsLike, Account Number LikeEqualsIn, Tin EqualsLike,

4. My code starts from here

   ```
         HashSet<String> hs1 = new HashSet<String>();
          HashSet<String> hs2 = new HashSet<String>();
           for (String match : arraylist2 ) {
            hs1.add(match);
         }
             for (String match : arraylist1) {
           hs2.add(match);
         }
         for (String match : hs2) {
        boolean b = hs1.add(match);
        if (b == false) {
            matchingFields = match;
            System.out.println("-----------------matching Elements--------------------- =  " + 
             matchingFields);

        } else {
            nonMatchingFields = match;
            System.out.println("-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  " + 
          nonMatchingFields);
        }
    }
   ```

4.below is the out put i'm getting, You can see i'm getting only nonmatching value there is no matching value.

```
    --------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Document Type Code Like Equals In
    ---------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Test  two 
   --------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Document Date Like Equals Between
   -----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Check Document  Equals 
   -----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Member Id Like Equals In
  -----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Dealer Number Like Equals In
    -----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Print  Equals 
   -----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Group Id Like Equals In
-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Fund Number Like Equals 
-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Tin Like Equals 
-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Account Type Like Equals In
```

-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Account Number Like Equals In
-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  Company Number Like Equals

Comment: Why is `selenium` and `selenium-webdriver` tagged?

Comment: Because my input two data i'm retrieving from a URL through TestNg selenium code

Comment: Doesn't matters, you can always construct a `HashSet<String>()` even without using _Selenium_

Comment: did you check if there was extra space (either at the beggining or at the middle or at the end of your Strings) ?

Comment: after removing extra space i'm getting out put in this format = [Document Date LikeEqualsBetween, Fund Number EqualsLike, Account Number LikeEqualsIn, Tin EqualsLike,

Comment: Then you aren't properly remove spaces

Answer (score 1):

I set this up with a simple main method and it seems to be working for me.  You may want to try it with a simple example like mine.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a1.add("a");
        a1.add("b");

        ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a2.add("c");
        a2.add("a");
        checkMatch(a1, a2);
    }


    public static void checkMatch(ArrayList<String> arraylist1, ArrayList<String> arraylist2 ) {
        HashSet<String> hs1 = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> hs2 = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String match : arraylist2 ) {
            hs1.add(match);
        }
        for (String match : arraylist1) {
            hs2.add(match);
        }
        for (String match : hs2) {
            boolean b = hs1.add(match);
            if (b == false) {
                String matchingFields = match;
                System.out.println("-----------------matching Elements--------------------- =  " + 
                        matchingFields);

            } else {
                String nonMatchingFields = match;
                System.out.println("-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  " + 
                        nonMatchingFields);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

-----------------matching Elements--------------------- =  a

-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  b

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result by using a single hashmap.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        ArrayList<String> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Check Document Equals" , "Document Date Like Equals Between", "Fund Number Like Equals" , "Account Number Like Equals In", "Tin Like Equals" , "Company Number Like Equals" , "Dealer Number Like Equals In", "Member Id Like Equals In", "Group Id Like Equals In", "Account Type Like Equals In", "Document Type Code Like Equals In", "Print Equals" , "Test two" ));
        ArrayList<String> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Document Date Like Equals Between", "Fund Number Equals Like", "Account Number Like Equals In", "Tin Equals Like", "Company Number Equals Like", "Dealer Number Like Equals"));

        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>(arraylist1);

        for (String match : arraylist2) {
            
            if (hs.contains(match)) {
                System.out.println("-----------------matching Elements--------------------- =  " + match);
            }
            else {                
                System.out.println("-----------------Not matching elements---------------------  =  " + match);
            }
        }

    }
}
```